# Rails same incoming route but different controller actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

A user clicks on a tag like example.com/pizza, and sees all the posts with the tag of pizza in the posts controller. I want people to also see all the "alternateposts" with the tag of pizza as well, but in a different controller.

rails routes throws an error saying its already in use. what's the best way to go about this?

**routes.rb**

```
  # TAGS
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'alternateposts#index', as: :tag
```

Comment: The `tag` alias is already in use, and the URI `tags/:tag` wil be overwritten if you declare it twice. How're your models and relationships defined?, your controllers? improve the question adding more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare multiple route with same URL.
In your case, the seconde URL will overload your first one.

You have to declare a single route with a single controller and return `posts` and `alternateposts` in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Antoine Dewaele is right. you don't declare multiple routes with same URL.
your route file is like this

```
get 'tags/:tag' => 'posts#index', :as => :tag
```

your route file should be like this

```
get 'tags/:tag' => 'posts#index', :as => :tag
get 'all_pizza' => 'all_pizza#index', :as => :all_pizza
```

For more info you can visit here [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Pizza was just an example of tag, not a resource. So don't make a route to get all pizza.